# Extracting specific information from a SQL server using Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

This is my first time creating a component for Joomla, and Im having a few problems understanding how certain things works. The current problem I have is getting different data out to my view.

My component is built using model-view-controller set up and this is the current code in view that brings the data up to the php file that shows it off :

```
class TimeplanViewTimeplaner extends JViewLegacy
{
    protected $items1;
    protected $items2;
    protected $items3;
    protected $items4;
    protected $items5;
    protected $items6;
    protected $items7;
    protected $pagination;
    protected $state;
    protected $params;

    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        $this->state      = $this->get('State');
        $this->items1 = $this->get('Items');
        $this->items2 = $this->get('Items');
        $this->items3 = $this->get('Items');
        $this->items4 = $this->get('Items');
        $this->items5 = $this->get('Items');
        $this->items6 = $this->get('Items');
        $this->items7 = $this->get('Items');
        $this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
        $this->params     = $app->getParams('com_timeplan');


        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
        {
            throw new Exception(implode("\n", $errors));
        }

        $this->_prepareDocument();
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

This is not the complete code, but it's the part that I think highlights my problem. I want $items 1 to 7 to get different hits, but currently I have to rely on $this->get('Items') to show data. My question is where can I find the code that feed $this->get('Items') with data?

This might be a basic question, or I might have to show of more code, but I need a pointer in the right direction to understand this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need to do exactly, but any "get" action is defined in the model of your component.

If you need to have different values for each of the above variables (`$items1`, `$items2`, etc...), then you will need to add conditions to your "get" function (such as `getListQuery` function) to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

All the data is generated in the model. So you can find the data being generated inside your model folder. The getItems and getPagination methods are defined in JModelList class. Also as the name of your view is Timeplaner so by default if timeplaner.php exists inside the model folder then it gets loaded. Check this link how a MVC framework works in Joomla https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Introduction .